# Run .EXE in using Azure ADF V2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm fairly new to Azure and I have setup an .exe file to run in an Azure ADF V2.

I my Custom Activity setup with the account and batch setup.

When I try to run the exe in debug it just keeps running indefinitely with no fail or anything.

The exe gets data from multiple web apis and loops through it using C# code and outputs to a database. I'm not looking for alternative to this. The exe works fine on my machine but not sure if it's working in Azure.

I've been setting everything up through the portal as well.

Here are the settings I have:

Command: program.exe

FolderPath: mycontainer

I copied the exe directly in to the container (mycontainer)

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: What is the question? Custom activity should be the right way to go.

Comment: I don't know if it's running or not it keeps hanging indefinitely. Any way to troubleshoot this? Has anyone ran into this issue? Are my configuration correct?

Comment: Try to compress the file and specific the properties like the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity).

Comment: You mentioned that you C# code will output to a database, right? So is there anything added in your database? Another way I guess is you could check your azure batch jobs in Azure portal. Is there any running jobs in batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Debug wasn't working, I had to actually Trigger the pipeline to get it work!

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure batch storage account should have a folder for each run (named based on the RunId Giod). Have you looked at the job output to see if there are any output files (there should always be an output directory with stdout.txt and stderr.txt files)? You can add Console.WriteLine commands in your EXE and they will write to the stdout.txt file - that may help you diagnose.[image]

Comment: Thanks Joel we have this, I'm waiting on setting up an SA account to see if that fixes this will report when done